# Toggle keypress event everytime condition changes

Tags: javascript, html

The following is my html code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="emp" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
                event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" >
```

I have a radiobutton which when `checked` should remove the `onkeypress` event and when `unchecked` should activate it. This is my `js`:

```
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (input.checked) {
      document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML="No";
      document.getElementById("emp").value="";
      document.getElementById("emp").removeAttribute("onkeypress");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML="Name";
      document.getElementById("emp").value="";
      document.getElementById("emp").setAttribute("onkeypress", "");
    }
});
```

But when I toggle the radiobutton, the code doesn't work properly. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `onkeypress` attribute to an empty string in the unchecked case, so it will do nothing, same as if the attribute is removed. You'd need to set it back to the original text, which you could get with `getAttribute` and store.

```js
var onkeypress_code = document.getElementById("emp").getAttribute("onkeypress");
input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (input.checked) {
      document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML="No";
      document.getElementById("emp").value="";
      document.getElementById("emp").removeAttribute("onkeypress");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML="Name";
      document.getElementById("emp").value="";
      document.getElementById("emp").setAttribute("onkeypress", onkeypress_code);
    }
});
```

But I would recommend doing this differently. You can use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` (removing the onkeypress from the HTML):

```js
function emp_onkeypress(event) {
    return (
        (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) ||
        (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)
    );
}
function checkbox_onchange(event) {
    if (input.checked) {
      document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML="No";
      document.getElementById("emp").value="";
      document.getElementById("emp").removeEventListener("keypress", emp_onkeypress);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML="Name";
      document.getElementById("emp").value="";
      document.getElementById("emp").addEventListener("keypress", emp_onkeypress);
    }
}
input.addEventListener('change', checkbox_onchange);
checkbox_onchange(); // update based on initial checkbox state
```

Or you can simply handle the checked/unchecked state in your keypress handler. If you define the keypress handler in your JS, you will have access to the `input` variable.

```js
function emp_onkeypress(event) {
    if (input.checked) {
        return;
    }
    return (
        (event.charCode > 64 && event.charCode < 91) ||
        (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)
    );
}
document.getElementById("emp").addEventListener("keypress", emp_onkeypress);

input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (input.checked) {
      document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML="No";
      document.getElementById("emp").value="";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML="Name";
      document.getElementById("emp").value="";
    }
});
```

Also, `charCode` is deprecated; `key` and `code` are the recommended APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to handle this feature in your `onkeypress` function, just check if the radio button is `checked` do anything you want, if not `return null`